# Onkeypress event using jquery not work

Tags: jquery

Hi i need help to solve my problem.
i've made a function for input data using jquery with onkeypress event (enter). i don't know why my function not work. 
here my jquery i hope someone can help me solve that with a correction in my code

```js
$('#netto').bind("enterKey",function(e){
if ($('#netto').val() == ''){
        alert ('Kolom Netto Kosong');
    }else{
        var data= $("#form_input").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            data:data,
            type:"POST",
            url:"../php/bkk/bkk_i.php",
            success: function(data){
                alert ("Data:" + data);

            }
        });
    }

    window.location.reload();
    clearInput();
});
$("form_input").submit(function(){
    return false;
});
function clearInput(){
    $("#form_input :input").each( function() {

    $('#nopol').val('');
    $('#netto').val('');

});

}

$('#netto').keyup(function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 13)
{
  $(this).trigger("enterKey");
}
});
```

**THIS the HTML**

```html
<div id="wrapper-body">
    <div id="kiri" class="btn btn-default">

    <div id="kiri1">
    <div class="btn btn-default">
        <form action="../php/bkk/bkk_i.php" id="form_input" method="post" >
        <table border=0>

         <tr>
                <td width=70>Tanggal</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text"  id="datepicker" type="text" name="datepicker" size=26> </td>
                <td width=1>
                <img src="../image/ok.png" class="button" name="ok" id="ok" style="height:35px; width:40px" />
                <img src="../image/save.png" class="button" name="save" id="save" style="height:33px; width:38px" />
                <img src="../image/show.png"  class="button" name="show" id="show" style="height:35px; width:40px"  />  
              </td>
           <tr>
                <td width=70>PO</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="po" type="text" name="po" maxlength="25" size="26" /> </td>
                <td width=1>  
                <img src="../image/edit.png"  class="button" name="edit" id="edit" style="height:35px; width:40px; " />
                <img src="../image/delete.png" class="button" name="delete" id="delete" style="height:35px; width:40px" />
                <img src="../image/print.png"  class="button" name="print" id="print" class="print" style="height:35px; width:40px;" />
             </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width=70>Material</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="material"type="text" name="material" maxlength="100" size="26" style="text-transform:uppercase" /> </td>
               <td width="1"><input type="text" id="no" type="text" name="no" maxlength="1" size="23" readonly="readonly"  style="visibility:hidden"/></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width=70>Kapal</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="kapal"type="text" name="kapal" maxlength="100" size="26"/> </td>
                <td width=1></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width=70>Lokasi</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="lokasi"type="text" name="lokasi" maxlength="20" size="26" style="text-transform:uppercase" /> </td>
                <td width=1></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width=70>No. Polisi</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="nopol" type="text" name="nopol" maxlength="10" size="26" style="text-transform:uppercase" /> </td>
                <td width=1></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width=70>Netto</td>
                <td width=10>:</td>
                <td width=30>
                <input type="text" id="netto" type="text" name="netto" maxlength="20" size="26"  /> </td>
                <td width=1></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width=70></td>
                <td width=10></td>
                <td width=30>

              </td>
                <td width=1>

              </td>
            </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: pls provide html as well

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @guradio i use jquery ver 1.11.3.

Comment: @RonyLoud w8 i will edit my code and repost it again

Comment: try use the event `.on("keypress")` then use a condition like `if(e.which == 13)`

Comment: What happens when you run the code shown? Do you get any errors in the console, or...?

Comment: @nnnnnn i didnt get any eror code but the enter function just not running i dont know why. and i think i've wrong in my jquery code

Comment: Where is the JS included in the page? You haven't wrapped the code in a document ready handler, so the `<script>` element would need to be at the end of the body just before the closing `</body>` (or after the elements it tries to select, anyway).

Comment: @nnnnnn i think jquery didnt need included in page. cz in there i've give function for directly call the key press function

Comment: I don't understand what you mean (in that last comment). You have to include jQuery in the page, and as already mentioned you have to include the JS shown in a script element that is *after* the elements it tries to bind event handlers to. Also, I just noticed that `$("form_input")` should be `$("#form_input")` (add the #).

Comment: @nnnnnn heheheeh... i've try different way to do it. and its running well